# How can a dynamically instantiated Vue Component be cached?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

In my application I instantiate a dialog component programmatically. The dialog can (does) contain a child component to show content. I accomplish this thus:

```js
// Create the containing dialog component.
// I don't care if this is cached or not, and it's easy
// to recreate.
//
var DialogComponent = Vue.extend(Dialog);
var instance = new DialogComponent({
    parent: parent,
    data: {...}
    propsData: {...}
});

// Compile the subcomponent string. In practice this would
// be built dynamically before being passed to
// Vue.compile()
// 
const template = '<ComponentName :binding="" ... />'
const x = Vue.compile(template);
const slotContent = {
    data() { return data},
    render: x.render,
    staticRenderFns: x.staticRenderFns
}

// Create a vnode from the compiled render functions. This
// is the part I am less confident in, as it appears the
// render function returned will always instantiate a new
// child component, and it feels like involving `instance`, 
// i.e. the dialog, is incorrect.
//
const vnode = instance.$createElement(slotContent);
instance.$slots.default = [ vnode ];

// Mount the dialog component to a DOM element. 
// 
var tmp = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(tmp);
instance.$mount(tmp);

// Hook the dialog close event to clean up the instance.
// In practice, when caching I would like to pull the
// child component out and only destroy the dialog instance.
// I can successfully set the child's vnode.data.keepAlive and
// persist the instance, but a new one gets created nonetheless.
// 
instance.$on('close', (e) => {
    instance.$el.parentNode.removeChild(instance.$el);
    instance.$destroy();
})
```

I believe this is the accepted way of accomplishing this, and it works flawlessly. However, each time the dialog goes away it is of course `$destroyed` and the component resets when it's shown again.

I now need a method of maintaining the subcomponent's state when the dialog closes and reopens. So imagine a dialog that shows a `new Date()` on creation— I need that same date to show up after the dialog is closed and reopened. I have tried various sprinklings of `<keep-alive>` to no avail, but I don't think this is the appropriate use of that component.

Caching the vnode successfully avoids the `compile` call, but because (I think) the returned render function instantiates a component instance (`ComponentName` in the example) it does not reuse the original `ComponentName`, even if I successfully avoid destroying it (`vm._isDestroyed == false`).

Ultimately I think I'd like to hit [line 73](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/b9de23b1008b52deca7e7df40843e318a42f3f53/src/core/vdom/create-component.js#L73) in vue/create-component.js when inserting the child component, but a breakpoint there never gets hit (which may be an unrelated webpack/source-maps thing).

**Is there a sane way of accomplishing the caching of a programmatically instantiated Vue component for later reuse similar to how `<keep-alive>` works?**

Comment: If it's the state of the component you're interested in maintaining,  perhaps vuex or another state management utility could suit?

Comment: That is a good suggestion, and may be what I end up doing. As is, though, I have a very simple API for creating the 'dialogs,' and some of the child state seems very trivial. I'd like to learn about how Vue performs in-memory caching, e.g. with the <keep-alive> component if possible.